# Understanding why plot of ODE system attributes wrong label to legend

Tags: plotting

I am trying to understand why the color-lable combinations are wrong on my plot.
Here is my sort of MWE of my ODE:

```
ClearAll["Global`*"];
system = {input'[t] == -g1*input[t],
          Aox'[t] == b1*ROS[t - 1] - g2*Aox[t]*ROS[t],
          ROS'[t] == b2*Pip[t - 1] + g1*input[t] - g2*Aox[t]*ROS[t],
          Pip'[t] == b3*SA[t - 1] - g3*Pip[t],
          SA'[t] == b4*ROS[t - 1] - g4*SA[t],
           input[0] == 1, Aox[0] == ROS[0] == Pip[0] == SA[0] == 0};
val = {input, Aox, ROS, Pip, SA};
sol = ParametricNDSolve[system, 
  val, {t, 0, 200}, {g1, b1, b2, g2, b3, b4, g3, g4}]
```

And here is for setting parameters and plotting:

```
pb1 = 1;
pg = 1;
pb2 = 1;
pg2 = 1;
pb3 = 1;
pb4 = 1;
pg3 = 1;
pg4 = 1;
Plot[
 Evaluate[
  Table[{
     input[pg, pb1, pb2, pg2, pb3, pb4, pg3, pg4][t],
     Aox[pg, pb1, pb2, pg2, pb3, pb4, pg3, pg4][t],
     ROS[pg, pb1, pb2, pg2, pb3, pb4, pg3, pg4][t],
     Pip[pg, pb1, pb2, pg2, pb3, pb4, pg3, pg4][t],
     SA[pg, pb1, pb2, pg2, pb3, pb4, pg3, pg4][t]} /. sol,
   {delta, 0.1, 2, 0.1}]],
 {t, 0, 40},
 PlotLegends -> ToString /@ val, PlotStyle -> ColorData[91] /@ val]
```

For some reason the color and legend do not mathch.

Comment: Presumably you mean `PlotStyle -> ColorData[91] /@ Range[5]`. Although `ColorData[97]` would provide better color contrast.

Comment: @BobHanlon God... Yeah, I guess that is what I mean... If you post an anwser I'll accept it since it fixed my problem. Thanks a lot! Still quite new to Mathematica. If you want to generalize I guess you could add Range[Length[val]]

Comment: `PlotStyle -> ColorData[97] /@ Range[Length[val]]` Either answer your own question or delete the question.